# Prove $\sigma(f)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and this $\sigma$-algebra is smallest s.t. $f$ measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and define:

$$\sigma(f)=\{f^{-1}(B):B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$$

Prove $\sigma(f)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and this $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest that makes $f$ measurable.

**My attempt:**

I could prove $\sigma(f)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. But i'm stuck in this part:

> This $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest that makes $f$ measurable.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that makes $f$ measurable.

The latter means that for any Borel set $B$ of $\Bbb R$ we have that $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{A}$.

But this just says $\sigma(f) \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. So $\sigma(f)$ is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already proved that $\sigma(f)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
Trivially, $f$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(f)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ such that $f$
is $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. By the very
definition of measurability, it follows that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{M}$
for each $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}$). This is precisely $\sigma(f)\subseteq\mathcal{M}$.
Therefore $\sigma(f)$ is the smallest sigma algebra on $X$ such
that $f$ is $\sigma(f)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}$)-measurable.